# Overlapping issue with label using material design in iOS devices

Tags: css, material-design

In iOS devices, label is getting overlapped when value is entered in a form. I have created form using [material design](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design) . Please help.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV4Sn.png)

Comment: You should provide a sample code or a JSFiddle for other users to see what you have done.

Comment: try adjusting .form-group.label-static label.control-label style top value in your css to fix this.

Comment: still not working in ios devices

Answer (score 0):

Don't provide text for label. You should provide text only for placeholder for MDCTextField either from storyboard or programmatically